# Unremovable 0 byte file in data dir

Tags: android, filesystems, android-4.4-kitkat

A working app of mine started throwing warnings to logcat all of a sudden on my 4.4.4 Kitkat device:

```
W/ContextImpl﹕ Failed to ensure directory: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures
```

All the photos and other data are unaccessable to the app.

After some digging it turns out that there's a seemingly 0 byte file in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data` with the package name of my app: `com.example.app`. No wonder that Android can't create a directory with the same name.

I have absolutely no idea how, when and this file got created. Or better to say, how, when and why the original directory got corrupted.

The strange thing is, that even though it's listed when I call either `list()` or `listFiles()` on the data dir itself, calling `exists()`, `isFile()`, `isDirectory()` on the file itself will all return `false`.

The file seems to have no uid or gid and no date/time associated with it. **It can neither be renamed nor deleted. Trying to clear the data of the  app will also not remove it, nor will uninstalling the app.**

What to do now? Changing the package name of the app so that a new directory can be created is obviously not an option here.

Comment: you can `shell` it and delete file from `cmd prompt.`

Comment: No I can't. Adb shell says: "rm failed for com.example.app, Device or resource busy"

Comment: try to force stop your app and try again.

Comment: The app is even unistalled by now as mentioned in the original post, but to no avail. I'll try rebooting the device.

Comment: seems like a bug. can you write steps to reproduce ?

Comment: No I can't, it came seemingly out of the blue. But rebooting removed the file, solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting removed the file, solving the problem. Still no idea how and why this happened though.